# how to get the new entered value in gridview in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on a project and using a gridview to view some data that is editable. I have some constrains on this data and I want to perform a front-end checking before the data is sent to the database. My code is as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
            CommandName="Update" Text="Update" onclientClick="check(this)"/>
```

And my JavaScript is as follows:

```
function check(up) {

    var ip, desc, rt;

    var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');

    var row = up.parentNode.parentNode;

    ip = row.cells[1].children[0].attributes[2].value;
    desc = row.cells[2].children[0].attributes[2].value;
    rt = row.cells[3].children[0].attributes[2].value;
    time = parseFloat(rt);
    alert(rt);

    if (ip === null || ip.match(/^ *$/) !== null) {
        alert('please enter IP Address');
        return false;
    }
    else if (desc === null || desc.match(/^ *$/) !== null) {
        alert('please enter description');
        return false;
    }
    else if (rt === null || rt.match(/^ *$/) !== null) {
        alert('please enter refresh time');
        return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(time)){
        alert('refresh time must be a number');
        return false;
    }
    else if (Number(time) < 1) {
        alert('the minimum refresh time is 1');
        return false;
    }
    else 
        return true;
}
```

The problem is that I always get the old value not the new one. How can I get the new values in JavaScript?
I'm using an `sqlDataSource` with my update query:

```
UPDATE Clients
SET ipAddress = @ipAddress, description = @description, refreshTime = @refreshTime
WHERE machineName = @MachineName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting row index from your row, try this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');

var row = up.parentNode.parentNode;

var rindex = row.rowIndex; // get gridview row index

ip = table.rows[rindex].cells[1].children[0].value;
desc = table.rows[rindex].cells[2].children[0].value;
rt = table.rows[rindex].cells[3].children[0].value;
```